# Multiple resources in Try-With-Resources - statments inside

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-with-resources

I'm trying to specify multiple resources in a single `Try-With-Resources` statement but my situation is a bit different from the ones I read on other posts.

I've just tried the following `Try-With-Resources`

```
public static String myPublicStaticMethod(BufferedImage bufferedImage, String fileName) {

try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", os);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
    ) {
    .....
    .....
    }
```

But my code is not able to compile with this error:

```
Resource references are not supported at language level '8'
```

So, as you can see, my aim is to declare `ByteArrayOutputStream os` and  `InputStream is` as resources of `Try-With-Resources` both but I have to call `ImageIO.write()` method before creating the InputStream.

Must I to use the usual **try-catch-finally** to close the streams?

Comment: Make sure your IDE language level is java 8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965221/try-with-resources-not-supported-at-this-language-level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only declare objects implementing `AutoCloseable` interface inside the *try-with-resources* block, so your `ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", os);` statement is invalid there.

As a workaround you can split this code into two try-catch-blocks, i.e.:

```java
try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", os);
    try(InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray())) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Make sure your [IDE language level is Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965221/try-with-resources-not-supported-at-this-language-level)

When you want to add extra lines of code which aren't creating autoclosable resource inside try with resources block then you can add specific method wrapping it, in your case:

```
private InputStream getInputStream() {
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", os);
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
}
```

And call it in try with resources:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream is = getInputStream()) {
```

I assume (as in your code) the extra lines relevant to creating the resource, if not just open an inner try with resources with your second resource as @PavelSmirnov suggested

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
public static String myPublicStaticMethod(BufferedImage bufferedImage, String fileName) {

try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()) {
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", os);
    .....
    }
```

You just declare resources used in try declaration, do the operations inside try block. Ofc you will need catch block also. Finally is not needed, except you wanna catch exceptions during closing of resources (suppressed exceptions)

Comment: OP want to write (ImageIO.write) to `os` before call `os.toByteArray()`